# Hover Over to Pause Marquee

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

I want to create a Marquee that scrolls some news articles but when the user hovers over it I need it to pause and when the user hovers out of it (onMouseOut) I need to ti start back up. This did not work:

```
<marquee onMouseOver="this.stop()" onMouseOut="this.start()">Text</marquee>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve this in a minimal amount of code?

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt work? its working fine for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The marquee tag has an attribute called `scrollamount` which controls how fast it goes. All we need to do is set the value to `0` when we hover in and set it back to `5` when we mouse out.

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/U9yFj/

```
$(function() {
    $('marquee').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).attr('scrollamount',0);
    }).mouseout(function() {
         $(this).attr('scrollamount',5);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah marquees are outdated but always useful for news scrolls ^.^ Adds quick and easy functionality to a simple website. Thanks! ~ On another note I think marquee is now depreciated now (?)

Comment: Don't knock old mate marquee, I am all about it

Comment: Then it would be nice to know whats the suitable vreplacemnet of marquee?

Answer (score 47):

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
my text here
</marquee>
```

You're using wrong case: onMouseOver,onMouseOut

Comment: Even using the smal onmouseover shows `this.stop()` is not a function error.

Comment: this solution is better than using jquery function.

Comment: worked for me (tested in chrome and internet explorer 10)

Comment: FYI, Camel-case is not problem while using on HTML attribute, it could problem inside vanilla JS.

Answer (score 17):

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    Go on... hover me (and hold the mouse over)!
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="5" direction="left" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount',0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount',5);">
 Your name, your address, your details scrolling through line
</marquee>
```

Hope this code will help someone who is use MARQUEE tag.

Comment: And this doesn't need anything else added? Like a <script> in the body? Thanks

Comment: @SiamakEnsafi Event Attribute on HTML does not require any TAG for executing Javascript on its value.

Answer (score 2):

```
<marquee id="mq" direction="right" loop="true" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click here" onclick="alert(txt.value);" />
    Some other text here</marquee>
```

Comment: The marquee element has never been a part of any HTML standard and, to be sure, the HTML5 spec marks it as obsolete. Please don't update questions about long obsolete, unspecified, never to be used elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the HTML marquee markup with

```
onmouseover="stop()"
```

followed by

```
onmouseout="start()"
```

Comment: Please write here the solution instead of including a link that could be broken in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Will do that from now onwards. It's basically marquee onmouseover="start()" onmouseout="stop()" as per the question. But the link I provided has got all other options like direction, speed and behavior manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `;` to your code  after closing the `()` .

Comment: No, Javascript even works without semicolons. And you shouldn't put semicolon after tag events such as `onclick`, `onmouseover`...